# How to access HTML tag in json object

Tags: javascript, html

[image]
I have JSON object and I want to access "content" which I have highlighted in the s2 snapshot so currently this is the situation "content": "". So if I place some div or some anchor tag in the content something like that "content": " " So How to access this url i.e href . Any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: What have you tried yourself? What are you stuck on. Please add a code sample of what you have now. For example have you tried parsing the JSON and access trough it's properties?

Comment: @MarkBaijens

Class Parser extends Component {
render() {
 return (
  <div>
    {
    sampleJSON.value.map((data,index)=>{
 console.log(data.body.content)
 })}
 </div>
  );
 }
}

Comment: but I want to access href link which is "content": "<a href="something.com"> </a>"

Comment: Please update your question with a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 0):

usually people recieve a json object in some type of request to an API
a json object literal is already a javascript object so you'd just assign it to a variable and access it like you would any js obj
watch out for the nested array as well

```
var obj = yourExampleJsonObject

console.log(obj.value[0].body.content)
```

also please [don't post code as an image](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557) in the future. Cheers!

Comment: but I want to access href link which is "content": "<a href="something.com"> </a>"

Answer (score 0):

```js
var obj = {
    "key": "value",
  "array": [{ 
    "id": "123456",
    "body": {
        "content": "<tag></tag>"
    }
  }],
}

console.log(obj.array[0].body.content);
```